# Displayin two different images on a window in OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to display two different images on a window using OpenGL. Something like what has been shown in the below image.

First image on the left side of window: img [nc x nr]

Second image on the right side of window: img2 [nc x ns]

[image]
image

I have written the below code for display routine:

```
void display(void)
{
   ///////////////////First Image////////////////////////
   glViewport( (GLsizei) 0, (GLsizei) 0, (GLsizei) nc, (GLsizei) nr );
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);               

   glRasterPos2i(0, 0);                                 
   glDrawPixels(nc,nr, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);

   ///////////////////Second Image////////////////////////
   glViewport( (GLsizei) 0, (GLsizei) nc, (GLsizei) nc, (GLsizei) ns );
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);               

   glRasterPos2i(0, nc);                                    
   glDrawPixels(nc,ns, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img2); 
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   glutSwapBuffers();                                   

}
```

When I run the program the window displays nothing; but when I comment out the display code for the second image, I can see image 1 in the left side of window.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried making the viewport big enough for both and just drawing them? I have a feeling that your second viewport change is what is hiding the first image you drew.

Comment: The viewport needs only be set once, you shouldnt reset it as this will override the original viewpoint. You should ideally divide the viewport by 2(half for each image) and then scale the two images to fit into one half of the viewport

Comment: @Borgleader : I initialized window to be :  glutInitWindowSize(2*nc,nr);

Comment: @sara_123 I'm talking about the viewport. Make the viewport be that size and then draw both things without changing it

Comment: @sara_123 The viewport is what you see in the Window. If you have multiple viewpoints you will not see everything. You only need one viewport for a window as in my answer.

Comment: @const_ref : But I did it before. I had several viewport's for different parts of the window. It was working correctly (At that time I had used glulookat and glvertex3f instead of glDrawPixels).

Comment: @sara_123 It was more likely a coincidence. Think of the viewport as your eyes. Your eyes can see multiple objects at the same time, each object doesnt need a new set of eyes to see it. Think of it logistically if you have 3000 models, you would need to set up 3000 viewports....highly unmanagable and very slow, both to set up and when rendering

Comment: @Borgleader: I commented out the second glviewport; and changed the first one to be glViewport( (GLsizei) 0, (GLsizei) 0, (GLsizei) 2*nc, (GLsizei) nr );
Is that what you meant?
I run the code, the window is still black.

Comment: @const_ref : Even if the objects (images) are not belong to the same scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void display(void)
{
   // Size the viewport to be big enough for two images
   glViewport( (GLsizei) 0, (GLsizei) 0, (GLsizei) screen_width, (GLsizei) screen_height );
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);               

   // Position first image starting at 0, 0
   glRasterPos2i(0, 0);   
   // Get the width and height of image as first two params                              
   glDrawPixels(img.width,img.height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);

   // Position second image starting after the width of the first image
   glRasterPos2i(img.width, 0);   
   // get width and height of second image as first two params                                 
   glDrawPixels(img2.width,img2.height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img2); 

   glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

This is the general idea. Obviously screen_height etc are named differently in your app but the viewport should be set to the size of the screen. The Raster position should be the start position of the images and the first 2 params of DrawPixels should be the width and height of your images. Each image does not need its own viewport, as this would be highly unmanageable(and extremely slow) when the number of images/models grow.

Comment: Can you suggest me a good book or website to learn more about OpenGL?

Comment: @const_ref: It's perfectly reasonable to use the viewport for setting the position and scaling (in pixels) an image to be drawn. Also glDrawPixels is deprecated and has been removed from modern OpenGL so don't use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are defining viewport two times. So the effect of first viewport is no longer in effect. Define only one viewport with height and width of screen.